# perl принудительно выставить %env

Tags: bash, perl

есть программа, которая запускается из .procmailrc по приходу письма. распечатка %env там одна, из за этого не работают некоторые библиотеки из зза переменных окружения. при ручном запуске при логине происходит сначала запуск .bashrc а потом уже запуск программы. и %env там совершенно другой.

теперь вопрос.

могу ли я передать программе perl параметрами нужные мне переменные в хеше %env ? иными словами доопределить при запуске хэш %env .

при запуске программы с помощью .procmailrc по приходу письма хеш %env такой

```
SHELLMETAS => &|<>~;?*[
HOME => /home/ipn2
HOST => master.test.ru
LASTFOLDER => /home/ipn2/log/incoming.mail
MSGPREFIX => msg.
SENDMAIL => /usr/sbin/sendmail
SHELLFLAGS => -c
MAILDIR => /home/ipn2
SENDMAILFLAGS => -oi
LOGNAME => ipn2
LINEBUF => 2048
DEFAULT => /var/mail/ipn2
ORGMAIL => /var/mail/ipn2
PROCMAIL_VERSION => 3.22
PATH => /home/ipn2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
LOGFILE => /home/ipn2/log/procmail.log
SHELL => /bin/bash
UMASK => 022
LOCKEXT => .lock
```

а при запуске в ручную при логине в шелл хеш такой:

```
ipn2@master:~$ perl t.pl
HOME => /home/ipn2
MANPATH => /home/ipn2/share/man
PERL_MM_OPT => INSTALL_BASE=/home/ipn2/perl5
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT => /home/ipn2/perl5
LESSOPEN => | /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
MAIL => /var/mail/ipn2
PWD => /home/ipn2
LANG => ru_RU.UTF-8
USER => ipn2
LOGNAME => ipn2
LESSCLOSE => /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
PERL_MB_OPT => --install_base "/home/ipn2/perl5"
PGDATABASE => imdata
SHLVL => 1
_ => /usr/bin/perl
PERL5LIB => /home/ipn2:/home/ipn2/lib:/home/ipn2/lib/perl5
PATH => /home/ipn2/bin:/home/ipn2/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SHELL => /bin/bash
TERM => xterm-256color
```

у меня поставлены либы локально, которые я поставить не могу глобально. из за этого не работает программа. в ручную работает, а с прокмайлрс нет.

как доопределить параметры %env ?

вот какой procmailrc

```
ipn2@master:~$ cat .procmailrc
:0c
/home/ipn2/log/incoming.mail
UMASK=022
LOGFILE=/home/ipn2/log/procmail.log

:0 : /home/ipn2/log/procmail.lock
* ^Subject.*
| /home/ipn2/t.pl

ipn2@master:~$
```

Comment: Но вот же у вас прямо в procmail.rc задаются две переменные окружения UMASK и LOGFILE попробуйте дописать те, которые нужны скрипту

Comment: помимо этого вы можете писать в %ENV в самом скрипте. perl5lib можно указывать в виде `use lib "путь"`.

Comment: Урра!!! зарработало, добавил переменные откружения в .procmailrc и все зарработало!!! Спасибо!!!